# RESTEasy server in OSGI can't process annotations

Tags: eclipse, rest, osgi, resteasy, equinox

I'm trying to use RestEasy inside Equinox. The only document that I've seen on the web for this configuration is here: http://sarbarian.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/resteasy-and-osgi-perfect-match/

I've followed the steps here and fixed a few things, but I got stuck at this point. When I call a url on the server, the call reaches the annotated class and method, but resteasy can't seem to serialize the result. I get the error:

```
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher 
SEVERE: Failed executing GET /sample2/hello
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.lang.String of media type: */*
```

I've created an OSGI bundle from RestEasy Jars (2.2.1.GA). The bundle automatically exports all packages. Somehow the OSGI class loader is failing to load a required class I guess. I'd really appreciate input, since I am really stuck!

Comment: It's difficult to answer from an OSGi perspective because I don't know which class Resteasy is trying to load. I assume it looks up the media type and response object in some configuration, and then loads a MessageBodyWriter instance based on the result. Is it possible to add logging, or run in a debugger, to find out this information? From there we could work out where to find the class and how to make it visible to Resteasy.

Comment: Ok, after lots of debugging, I think I found the problem. Recent versions of RestEasy are using meta-inf/services method to declare classes which handle xml/json/etc.. This mechanism (SPI) does not exist in OSGI, hence, the RestEasyProviderFactory instance never ends up with the content-handling_type mappings. So I need to find a way of assigning these content handlers. I'm trying to figure out how resteasy uses SPI to fill this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same issues.  In my effort to resolve this I created the following item:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-640

From my research I I ended up going with the following options:

- A simple code example of how an OSGi bundle can use an embedded Resteasy instance:  bitbucket.org/mark1900/resteasy-osgi-embedded
- A simple code example of how an OSGI bundle can export a Resteasy Service that other OSGi bundles can integrate and use:  bitbucket.org/mark1900/resteasy-osgi-service

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is really going to be useful